# Webmin login keeps looping to session_login.cgi

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, webmin

I've had a working webmin setup on a VPS, however after trying to force it to connect via HTTPS I've done goof somewhere and now whenever I try to login the login page doesn't display correctly (no blue rectange background) and trying to login via `https://server1.domain.me:10000` keeps redirecting me to `https://server1.domain.me:10000/webmin/session_login.cgi`, which is again a login page.

Before it began malfunctioning, I had the following file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.me
        ServerName domain.me
        ServerAlias www.domain.me

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.me/
        <Directory />
                RedirectMatch temp ^/$ /public_html
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/domain.me>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/domain.me/redmine>
                AllowOverride None
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RailsBaseURI /redmine
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
        </Directory>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        RailsEnv production
        RailsBaseURI /redmine 

</VirtualHost>
```

When I tried to force webmin (and owncloud if that matters) to use HTTPS I created a new Virtualhost for port 443 using my SSL keys and updated Virtualhost for port 80 to proxy all `http://domain.me/webmin` to `https://server1.domain.me:10000` (I kept commented-out configs for you to see what I've tried):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.me
        ServerName server1.domain.me
        alias /owncloud /var/www/domain.me/owncloud

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.me/

        SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/server1_domain_me.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/server1.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl.crt/COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt

        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

#       <Location /webmin>
#               RewriteEngine On
#               #RewriteRule (.*) https://server1.domain.me:10000/$1 [R,L]
#               ProxyPass https://server1.domain.me:10000/
#               ProxyPassReverse https://server1.domain.me:10000/
#       </Location>

        <Directory /var/www/domain.me/owncloud>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all

                Satisfy Any

                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        RewriteEngine on
                        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                                RewriteEngine On
                                RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/owncloud$
                        </IfModule>
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>


#       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
#        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
#                AllowOverride None
#                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
#                Order allow,deny
#                Allow from all
#        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

</VirtualHost>
```

and updated my domain.me virtualhost file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.me
        ServerName domain.me
        ServerAlias www.domain.me

        #SSLEngine On
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        <Proxy *>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.me/
        <Directory />
                RedirectMatch temp ^/$ /public_html
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/domain.me>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/domain.me/redmine>
                AllowOverride None
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
                RailsBaseURI /redmine
                PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
        </Directory>

        <Location /owncloud>
                ProxyPass https://server1.domain.me/owncloud/
        </Location>

        <Location /server1>
                ProxyPass https://server1.domain.me/webmin/
        </Location>

       ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerSignature On

        RailsEnv production
        RailsBaseURI /redmine


        #ProxyPassReverse /owncloud https://server1.domain.me/owncloud/
        #ProxyPassReverse /webmin https://server1.domain.me:10000/



</VirtualHost>
```

I also added the lines `webprefix=/webmin`, `webprefixnoredir=1` and `referer=domain.me` to `/etc/webmin/config`

However, something is clearly wrong here because I cannot login to webmin at all. I've been searching the web for an answer for the past 5 hours, tried a lot of thing and still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

There are 4 critical (and undocumented!) keys to get this to work, as I found through much aggravation!

1) When you edit `/etc/webmin/config`, make sure there is NO WHITE SPACE at the end of the `webprefix=/webmin` line. That will fix the problem where the login screen formatting is funky.

2) You need to be extremely precise in your use of slashes in your ProxyPass (and they don't match the official documentation!)

```
ProxyPass /webmin/ http://localhost:10000/
ProxyPassReverse /webmin/ http://localhost:10000/
```

3) You need to include cookie ProxyPass lines (again not in the documentation!).

```
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain /webmin/ http://localhost:10000/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /webmin/ http://localhost:10000/
```

4) When you browse to Webmin, you MUST INCLUDE a trailing slash!

```
http://your.domain.name/webmin/
```

*** UPDATE ***

Pertaining to point 4:

To make sure the trailing slash is always present when you browse to Webmin, add these lines (prior to your proxy pass, if it matters?). With this added, if you forget to add the slash, Apache will simply do it for you:

```
RewriteEngine On                    
RewriteRule ^/webmin$ /webmin/ [R]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I installed webmin set up apache with it, and after login screen, no redirection happened.But @MUHAHA was right. I set up my webmin with no /webmin directory, no nuthin!

I wrote a CNAME redirection rule in my domain provider. CNAME webmin.example.com to my raspberry pi's dynamic-dns service name.

my webmin.conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName webmin.example.com
  ServerAlias webmin.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:10000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10000/
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain / http://localhost:10000/
  ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / http://localhost:10000/
</VirtualHost>
```

after that i installed webmin... you know! :)

an then thanks to @MUHAHA, i changed that line 4043 in  /usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl file

```
change
&write_data("Location: $prot://$hostport$in{'page'}\r\n");
to
&write_data("Location: $prot://$host$in{'page'}\r\n");
```

and everythings peachy! Login redirects to the main page with ease!

Answer (score 1):

@Buvinj 
Im afraid, that this isnt enough..

To use proper SSL on Proxy, is needed to disable miniservers SSL

/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf

```
ssl=0
ssl_redirect=1
cookiepath=/webmin
```

/etc/webmin/config

```
webprefix=/webmin
webprefixnoredir=1
```

There are still problems with redirect after login, so this should help:

on webmin host edit file /usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl

```
and on line 4043 replace
&write_data("Location: $prot://$hostport$in{'page'}\r\n");
to
&write_data("Location: $prot://$host$in{'page'}\r\n");
```

Source: 
https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/discussion/600155/thread/6eb89f60/

But it doesnt work for me, i am redirected to root context (/) after login, not to /webmin context

EDIT: 
$prot is always evaluated as http, even if you have ssl_redirect=1 in miniserv.conf

/usr/share/webmin/miniserv.pl

```
&write_data("Location: https://$hostport$config{'cookiepath'}$in{'page'}\r\n");
```

Rewrite rule for Location: in headers should also fix this problem.

EDIT2:
https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/350

https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/351